# Chart.js doughnut animate/draw clockwise

Tags: chart.js

Currently, my chart.js doughnut starts at the top and animates clockwise. I would like to reverse animation to start at the top and animate anti-clockwise.

```
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
  options: {
    cutoutPercentage: 50,
    circumference: 1.6 * Math.PI,
    animation:{
        animateRotate: true,
        render: false,
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Reverse the data sorting

This is not an answer specifically on ***how to animate*** the ChartJs anti-clockwise, but i think it'll solve your problem.

I had an issue where I wanted to show one Bar chart and one Pie chart with the same data, and the Bar chart had to be sorted by number (greater to smaller). This is what I got, firstly:

[First attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHjvc.png)

But, as you can see, because the Pie chart is animated clockwised, the 'order' of the data differs from the Bar chart to the Pie chart. In the Bar chart, I had Blue, Red and Yellow, and in the Pie chart, visually speaking, I had Yellow, Red and Blue.

What I did was, after generating the Bar chart, reversing the labels, data and colors arrays. See:

```
var backgroundColors = [bgColor1, bgColor2, ...];
var borderColors = [bdColor1, bdColor2, ...];

dataArrayReversed = dataArray.reverse();
labelsArrayReversed = labelsArray.reverse();
backgroundColorsReversed = backgroundColors.slice(0, dataArray.length).reverse();
borderColorsReversed = borderColors.slice(0, dataArray.length).reverse();
```

Also, you'll need to reverse the legend order in the chart declaration, so it stays ordered:

```
 var pieChart = new Chart(ctxPie, {
                        type: 'pie',
                        data: {
                             labels: labelsArrayReversed,
                             datasets: [
                                  data: dataArrayReversed,
                                  backgroundColor: backgroundColorsReversed,
                                  borderColors: borderColorsReversed,
                                  borderWidth: 2
                             ]
                        },
                        options: {
                            legend: { reverse: true }
                        }
                    });
```

[Yay!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFAx5.png)

The animation is clockwise, but the visual effect is correct.

It's the same for doughnut charts.